# Javascript code executing only once

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a simple jquery calendar. Here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9qzjLt1j/

HTML:

```
<div id="boxupload" class="box_upload">
    <div colspan="2" class="linea">
        <div><button type="button" class="close" id="close">&times;</button></div>
        <div width="300px" id="form_title" class="box_title title">Acerca de mi</div>
    </div>
    <div><hr style="margin:0px"></div>
    <div colspan="2" class="linea">
        <div id="form_subtitle" class="box_subtitle title">Puedes indicar la fecha en la que escribes acerca de ti, y en futuro, si tu o tu vida cambia, escribir otro texto.</div>
    </div>
    <div colspan="10" style="width: 100%; border-top: 5px solid #EF4F69;">
        <div style="padding: 30px 0; min-height: 340px; background: #f2f2f2;">
            <div id="list_year" class="fl_l">
                <div style="padding: 0 0px 0 50px;" id="moveup">Up</div>
                <ul id="year-picker" style="height: 290px; overflow: hidden;">
                    <li class="year 2014"><a data-year="2000" href="#">2000</a></li>
                    <li class="year 2014"><a data-year="2001" href="#">2001</a></li>
                    <li class="year 2014"><a data-year="2002" href="#">2002</a></li>
                    <li class="year 2014"><a data-year="2003" href="#">2003</a></li>
                    <li class="year 2014"><a data-year="2004" href="#">2004</a></li>
                    <li class="year 2014"><a data-year="2005" href="#">2005</a></li>
                    <li class="year 2014"><a data-year="2006" href="#">2006</a></li>
                    <li class="year 2014"><a data-year="2007" href="#">2007</a></li>
                    <li class="year 2014"><a data-year="2008" href="#">2008</a></li>
                    <li class="year 2014"><a data-year="2009" href="#">2009</a></li>
                    <li class="year 2014"><a data-year="2010" href="#">2010</a></li>
                    <li class="year 2014"><a data-year="2011" href="#">2011</a></li>
                    <li class="year 2014"><a data-year="2012" href="#">2012</a></li>
                    <li class="year 2014"><a data-year="2013" href="#">2013</a></li>
                    <li class="year 2014"><a data-year="2014" href="#">2014</a></li>
                    <li class="year 2015"><a data-year="2015" href="#">2015</a></li>
                    <li class="year 2016"><a data-year="2016" href="#">2016</a></li>
                    <li class="year 2016"><a data-year="2017" href="#">2017</a></li>
                    <li class="year 2016"><a data-year="2018" href="#">2018</a></li>
                    <li class="year 2016"><a data-year="2019" href="#">2019</a></li>
                    <li class="year 2016"><a data-year="2020" href="#">2020</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div  style="padding: 0 0px 0 40px;" id="movedown">Down</div>
            </div>
            <div id="list_month" class="fl_l">
                 <ul id="month-picker">
                    <li data="01" class="mounth 01"><a data-year="2015" data-month="1" href="#">Enero</a></li>
                    <li data="02" class="mounth 02"><a data-year="2015" data-month="2" href="#">Febrero</a></li>
                    <li data="03" class="mounth 03"><a data-year="2015" data-month="3" href="#">Marzo</a></li>
                    <li data="04" class="mounth 04"><a data-year="2015" data-month="4" href="#">Abril</a></li>
                    <li data="05" class="mounth 05"><a data-year="2015" data-month="5" href="#">Mayo</a></li>
                    <li data="06" class="mounth 06"><a data-year="2015" data-month="6" href="#">Junio</a></li>
                    <li data="07" class="mounth 07"><a data-year="2015" data-month="7" href="#">Julio</a></li>
                    <li data="08" class="mounth 08"><a data-year="2015" data-month="8" href="#">Agosto</a></li>
                    <li data="09" class="mounth 09"><a data-year="2015" data-month="9" href="#">Septiembre</a></li>
                    <li data="10" class="mounth 10"><a data-year="2015" data-month="10" href="#">Octubre</a></li>
                    <li data="11" class="mounth 11"><a data-year="2015" data-month="11" href="#">Noviembre</a></li>
                    <li data="12" class="mounth 12"><a data-year="2015" data-month="12" href="#">Diciembre</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="list_day" class="fl_l" style="padding: 0 80px;">
                <div>
                    <div class="fl_l day_week">Ln</div>
                    <div class="fl_l day_week">Ma</div>
                    <div class="fl_l day_week">Mi</div>
                    <div class="fl_l day_week">Ju</div>
                    <div class="fl_l day_week">Vi</div>
                    <div class="fl_l day_week">Sa</div>
                    <div class="fl_l day_week">Do</div>
                </div>
                <div class="mounth_day clearfix">
                    <div id="week1">
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="week2">
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="week3">
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="week4">
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="week5">
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="week6">
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                        <div class="fl_l day" data-day="" data-month="" data-year=""></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div>
            <div id="block_bttn_left" class="btns_left">
                <div class="fl_l btn_left">pic</div>
                <div class="fl_l btn_left">pic</div>
                <div class="fl_l btn_left">pic</div>
            </div>
            <div id="close_button" class="bttn btn_cancelar">Cancelar</div>
            <div id="save_button" class="bttn btn_guardar">Guardar</div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Main function for updating calendar
        function updateCalendar(fCurrentMonth, fCurrentYear) {
            // Get month's number of days
            function daysInMonth(month, year) {
                return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
            }

            // Get the starting day of a month
            function dayStart(month, year) {
                var day = new Date(year + "-" + month + "-01").getDay();
                day = (day===0) ? 7 : day;

                return day;
            }

            // Assign the above functions to variables
            var dayStart = parseInt(dayStart(fCurrentMonth, fCurrentYear));
            var daysInMonth = parseInt(daysInMonth(fCurrentMonth, fCurrentYear));

            // Reset day values
            $("#list_day .day").text("");

            // Fill in calendar days with values
            var i = 1;
            $("#list_day .day").slice(parseInt(dayStart) - 1).each(function() {
                $(this).text(i);

                $(this).attr("data-day", i);
                $(this).attr("data-month", fCurrentMonth);
                $(this).attr("data-year", fCurrentYear);

                if(i == daysInMonth) {
                return false;
                }

                i++;
            });

            // Hide empty calendar rows
            if((dayStart + daysInMonth) <= 35) {
                $("#list_day #week6").hide();
            } else {
                $("#list_day #week6").show();
            }

            // Hide empty calendar rows
            if((dayStart + daysInMonth) <= 28) {
                $("#list_day #week5").hide();
            } else {
                $("#list_day #week5").show();
            }
        }

        // Get current month
        function getCurrentMonth() {
            var currentDate = new Date();
            var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth();

            return parseInt(currentMonth) + 1;
        }

        // Get current year
        function getCurrentYear() {
            var currentDate = new Date();
            var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();

            return parseInt(currentYear);
        }

        // On page load, set calendar to current date
        updateCalendar(getCurrentMonth(), getCurrentYear());

        // Update calendar when choosing year
        $("#list_year .year a").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $("#list_year .year a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");

            var currentYear = $(this).data("year");

            $("#list_month .mounth a").attr("data-year", parseInt(currentYear));

            var currentMonth = $("#list_month .mounth a").data("month");
            currentYear = $("#list_month .mounth a").data("year");

            updateCalendar(parseInt(currentMonth), parseInt(currentYear));
        });

        // Update calendar when choosing month
        $("#list_month .mounth a").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $("#list_month .mounth a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");

            $("#list_day .day").attr("style", "");

            var currentMonth = $(this).data("month");
            var currentYear = $(this).data("year");

            updateCalendar(parseInt(currentMonth), parseInt(currentYear));
        });

        // Function for changing day color
        function picker_set_bg(day, month, year, color) {
            var selector = "[data-day="+parseInt(day)+"][data-month="+parseInt(month)+"][data-year="+parseInt(year)+"]";
            $(selector).css("background", color)
        }
    });
```

When I select a year and a month, it works. And, when a month is already active and I decide to change the year, it works for the first time. But after changing it once, when clicking again on other years it doesn't work. It's not giving any JS errors, it's just not working. First I have to change the month again, so I can change the year.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is not working is because you have mixed the use between retrieving the year using the jQuery data() method vs. accessing the HTML attribute directly using the attr() method.

NB: Updating the year using the data method will not update the HTML 5 attribute, it will update the jQuery data reference it has stored against the DOM element. So if you inspect actually the HTML element, the data-year element will be unaltered from what it was originally set.

LOC 83 should be updated to retrieve the year using the data method as so:

```
$("#list_month .mounth a").data("year", parseInt(currentYear));
```

This alone will fix the issue.

However you could also remove the LOC 85 as currentYear was already initialised and set correctly on LOC 81.

```
var currentYear = $(this).data("year");
...
currentYear = $("#list_month .mounth a").data("year");
```

Please see forked fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9qzjLt1j/2/